# Usage of subject-verb inversion in dependent clauses

Tags: grammar

I am so sorry to repeat my question, but I cannot yet understand it.

Could you please readily or freely explain the difference between these? I can not understand their differences...

> I know what **is** the difference between these.
>
> I know what the difference **is** between these.

Or, when/where are they interchangeable? And what is the difference between them?

> I know who **are** you
>
> I know who you **are**

Comment: I have a hunch that you might confuse yourself with the examples "I know who my friend is." vs "I know who is my friend."in [this previous question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19667/3281). Which, unfortunately, both of them are possible. This question is essentially a duplicate of the previous question. It is just that there seems to be no satisfying answer to you yet.

Comment: @DamkerngT. do you mean "I know who my friend is" and "I know who is my friend" both are possible and correct? I thought only one is correct.

Comment: @Man_From_India "I know who my friend is" is the basic construction. "I know who is my friend", which is also correct (and that's an unfortunate example the OP used in their previous question), emphasizes the difference of who is my friend, and who is not. For example, see http://books.google.com/books?id=y2_TV8ZJV6YC&pg=PA49. Actually, we use this kind of construction all the time, for example, "I know what is right and what is wrong." Maybe it's just "who" that makes it sound weird.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever I said in my last answer is correct, but there needs to be some addition. Here I am trying to explain your question. My first impression was that out of the two quoted example sentences in the original post only one was correct. But after going through the comment of @DamkerngT. I am sure both of the example sentences are correct.

Consider the following example -

> **Mr A is my friend.**
>
> Now if I want to make this sentence interrogative it will be - **Who is
> my friend?** The subject is **Mr. A**. Similarly **Mr. A** can be the object of
> the sentence having the same meaning - **My friend is Mr. A**. And now if
> we make this sentence interrogative the inversion occurs - **Who is my friend?**

Your example sentence is not an interrogative one, instead an assertive sentence. So the depending clause also will be assertive.

> **I know Mr. A is my friend.** - **I know who is my friend.** ( When we make "**Mr. A is my friend**" interrogative, no inversion occurs. So "**I know who is my friend**" here also no inversion will occur.)
>
> **I know my friend is Mr. A** - **I know my friend is who** - **I know who my friend is**. ( When we make "**My friend is Mr. A**" interrogative, inversion occurs - **Who is my friend**. To make "**who is my friend**" assertive we inverse again. So it comes down to - **I know who my friend is**.)

I know this answer is a little bit clumsy, but I didn't find any other way to explain it.
Please let me now after reading this answer what all clarification you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should inverse subject-verb when you are asking question. 
The sentence - I know who you are - is meant to be assertive, not interrogative. So you should keep sub + verb straight.
The sentence - Do you know how the patient is - is meant to be interrogative, so make the main clause interrogative ( invert sub + verb arrangement), but keep the other clauses plain assertive, and hence no inversion.
I think you got it. Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: First, thank you so much. Moreover, I know almost 90% of it's grammar, but I am confused with meanings of my "original questions".

Comment: Did my reply above help?

Comment: Thank you so much, but I could not find my original answers.

Comment: I think that my questions need a more long range answer.

Comment: The short answer is that "I know who are you" is incorrect, and as such has no meaning.

Comment: You have two example sentences, and for each one there is an alternate version. Right? In my answer I have clearly mentioned how to write such kind of sentences, and so out of four examples that you have wrote only two is correct. Here are the correct ones - 1. I know who you are and 2. I know what the difference between these two is. Other examples that you have given are wrong.

Comment: I am ready to help you out if you have still confusion, regarding my answer as well as anything else regarding this.

Comment: I am so confused...

Comment: Please tell where exactly your confusion is. (Oh, :) you consider this sentence I just wrote. Consider the position of "is")

Comment: I can well understand their grammars and when/where we must use each of them as a question sentence et cetera, but the only thing which I can not understand is the fact that is my original question that I have just edited

Comment: Jim and I had already told that there is no difference as one of the two alternatives is wrong. And I have already mentioned which ones are correct.